# Unschedule a post

Tags: posts, scheduled-posts

I have some posts scheduled for tomorrow.  I want instead to remove the scheduled date and simply publish them manually when I am ready.

I can't find anything about this.

Does just setting them to "Draft" accomplish this? When I change the status from "scheduled" to "draft", the date remains.

Answer (score 2):

To revert from *scheduled* to *draft* without publishing immediately this works for me (WordPress 3.9.1 )

1. change scheduled date to yesterday
2. OK
3. Save as draft

done

Answer (score 1):

Setting the post status to "draft" will prevent the posts from publishing on the scheduled date. If you leave the date for the post in the future you will continue to see the Schedule button in the publish box. Clicking this will reschedule the post to publish on the specified date and time.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your "schedule" to be NOW (or maybe even in the past) and it will publish immediately. See [this article](http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/schedule-a-post/#un-scheduling-a-post) for additional details.

That said, to my knowledge there is not a way to "remove" the schedule -- only edit it.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to publish immediately; I just want it held as a draft with no publish date.